# Batch include files while keeping the namespace clean

Tags: php

I've been using the following snippet to include multiple files:

```
foreach(glob(APP_PATH."libs/*.php") as $path)
{
 include $path;
}
```

The thing is, I don't want to have the $path variable available inside the included files.

---

*Fictitious solution:*

```
include unset($path);
```

This would have worked if unset returned the value of the unsetted variable. It doesn't though. It returns void.

Comment: unset it after the loop?

Comment: I could but the variable would still be accessible inside the included files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own `unset` that returns the value...

```
function unsetr(&$value) {
    $result = $value;
    unset($value);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: That's great to see! Good luck!

Comment: Is adding "r" to the end of the function name a common practice for indicating that the function returns a value? If yes, can you give me an example of another PHP function that have embraced this practice?

Comment: Not that I know of. I do not believe that suffixing `r` is common practise for functions that return values. It's just that I couldn't think of a creative name.

Comment: Thanks! I can't help but ask - are you really 14?

Comment: Yes. Not trolling here. Do I really look *that* old in my picture? ;)

Comment: It says 14 in your profile. I couldn't say how old / young you look in the picture :) Anyway your knowledge of programming is really impressive.

Answer (score 2):

as your using foreach, after every loop the variable is reset and reused.

for example:

```
foreach(glob(APP_PATH."libs/*.php") as $path)
{
    include $path;
    //$path is now set to the next variable.
}
```

so you only need to unset `$path` once at the end of the foreach loop.

for example:

```
foreach(glob(APP_PATH."libs/*.php") as $path)
{
    include $path;
}
unset($path);
```

Jobs done now, $path is totally free and clear from the memory.

---

have you tried the following.

```
function HideString(&$_)
{
    $t = $_;
    unset($_);
    return $t;
}

foreach(glob(APP_PATH."libs/*.php") as $path)
{
    include HideString(&$path);
}
```

Comment: But the variable would still be accessible inside the included files.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent that the $path is available inside the included files try to use `eval("include $path;")`. Im not sure what happens to vars inside eval()...

Put it into a function/method, then it is only available inside the function (namespace).

Comment: you would really use eval for a small job like that ?

Comment: I would use eval() if its the onliest solution... For example this http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php#L1142

Comment: the reason eval is used there is to bring a generated class into scope, them rules don't apply here.